# sdk bundle install java error

Tags: java, sdk, bundle

I have tried to install sdk bundle on windows 8 64 bit and windows 7 64 bit machines.

After unpacking to c:\development dir I try to run te eclispe.exe from \adt-bundle-windows\eclipse and I get same error for both:

```
![error message][1]
"a java runtime enviroment JRE or JDK must be available to run eclipse. No java virtual machine found in c:\development\adt-bundle-windows\eclipse\jre..."
```

There is no jre directory in the installed `c:\development...` therefore the error.op

I tried installing java manually to the eclipse directory but it did not create a jre directory so error came up the same.

My understanding from the install instructions is that everything needed is provided in the "bundle"!

What am I missing?  Why is the java stuff not there?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the JRE installad on your machine, then go to Properties of my computer > Advanced tab > Select Environment Variables

Then in the section of System variables, look for the variable "Path" and edit that, and add you JRE path there with a semicolon.

like

";C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin"